# Should calculations be done within the insert method or the getter method within Ruby Class?

Tags: ruby

I am going through an Interview Cake question and they have the calculations done upon insertion of a new value. My instinct was to put that logic in the getter method and I was hoping for some insight on best practices.

Their Solution:

```
# Write a class TempTracker with these methods:
#
# insert()—records a new temperature
# getMax()—returns the highest temp we've seen so far
# getMin()—returns the lowest temp we've seen so far
# getMean()—returns the mean of all temps we've seen so far
# getMode()—returns a mode of all temps we've seen so far

class TempTracker
  def initialize
    # for mode
    @occurrences = [0] * 111 # array of 0s at indices 0..110
    @max_occurrences = 0
    @mode = nil

    # for mean
    @total_numbers = 0
    @total_sum = 0.0 # mean should be float
    @mean = nil

    # for min and max
    @min_temp = nil
    @max_temp = nil
  end

  def insert(temperature)
    # for mode
    @occurrences[temperature] += 1
    if @occurrences[temperature] > @max_occurrences
      @mode = temperature
      @max_occurrences = @occurrences[temperature]
    end

    # for mean
    @total_numbers += 1
    @total_sum += temperature
    @mean = @total_sum / @total_numbers

    # for min and max
    @max_temp = temperature if @max_temp.nil? || temperature > @max_temp
    @min_temp = temperature if @min_temp.nil? || temperature < @min_temp
  end

  def get_max
    @max_temp
  end

  def get_min
    @min_temp
  end

  def get_mean
    @mean
  end

  def get_mode
    @mode
  end
end
```

Insert and getter methods that I wrote initially:

```
// ... 

  def insert(temp)
    @max = temp if @max.nil? || @max < temp
    @min = temp if @min.nil? || @min > temp

    @total_sum += temp
    @total_numbers += 1

    @occurrences[temp] += 1
  end

// ...

  def get_mean
    @total_sum / @total_numbers
  end

  def get_mode
    @occurrences.each_with_index.max[1]
  end
end
```

Any help understanding if/ why having the calculation logic in the insert method would be hugely helpful!

Comment: Note that in Ruby including "get" in an accessor method is strongly discouraged. Why not do `@temperatures.max` using [`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max)? This avoids having to keep these fields up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Insert is a state-changing operation. It makes sense to reflect all the changes right there on the spot. Get, on the other hand, does not change state, it simply reads it.

Imagine that you do one insert and a hundred reads. It is not very efficient to repeat calculations on each get, as the result can't possibly change since the last time. Waste of resources, but can make for somewhat cleaner code.

---

*I just noticed that I assumed a read-heavy workload. In a write-heavy workload, where you write more than you read, it's the other way around. Efficiency dictates that you put calculations in the getter. There's no one true answer, it's always a tradeoff, is what I'm trying to say.*